# Reversing array, pop method in loop not popping to completion

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

*note: I have been looking at code for hours now and am at the point where I am beginning to question the spelling of every word or wonder if I am dyslexic- I know this is an easy question*

I am looking to write a basic function (without the use of standard JavaScript `reverse` method) that given an array, creates a new array with the same values in reverse order.

Why does this function as written pop "C" and "B", but not "A"?

```
function reverseArray(arr) {
    var reversedArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var popped = arr.pop(i);
        reversedArr.push(popped);
    }
    return reversedArr;
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

This should log ["C", "B", "A"] however it is logging → ["C", "B"] and when I log arr within the function it holds onto "A".

I fixed this by adding `reversedArr.push(arr.pop(arr[0]));` after the for loop and before the return statement which fixes the problem, but if the for loop is written to continue while i is less than the array length and when the array only contains "A", the length is one, and i is 0, shouldn't it also pop "A"?

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you call `pop(i)` you are removing an element from the array, so, the lenght becomes 2. You can just copy the value with `arr[i]` instead and starting from `arr.length-1` to 0.

Comment: You could also just change your `for` loop to go from `arr.length` to `0` and then push the elements as you loop.  `for(var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)`.

Comment: As Martin said, in your code, you should save the initial arr.length value and use it. P.S. and `pop` doesn't have any arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a pop on array it will permanently take that item out of the array and changes it's length. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

So, in your code you should use

```
var popped = arr[i];
```

And do the reverse iteration as below:

```
for (var i = arr.length -1; i>=0 ; i--)
```

Comment: Thank you! Answers the question and provides a fix within the context that I asked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function reverseArray(arr) {
  var reversedArr = [];
  while (arr.length > 0) {
    reversedArr.push(arr.pop())
  }
  return reversedArr;
}
```

How does this work?

`pop` does not take a parameter and just removes the last element, no need to keep track of an index. Just keep doing this until the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using pop method.

```
function reverseArray(arr) {
    var loopNumber = arr.length 
    var reversedArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {
        var popped = arr.pop();
        reversedArr.push(popped);
    }
    return reversedArr;
}

console.log(reverseArray(arr));
```